# Слушатель клавиши Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

Как сделать слушателя кнопки в Питоне? Аля: нажал на клавишу CTRL -> выполнилась функция f()

Windows/Python 3.6.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, [`pynput`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput) (`pip install pynput`). Пример из официальной документации:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Жрет любые символы (`Fn+`, `*.Lock`(`NumLock`, `CapsLock`), `Alt` - все, что угодно).

Чтобы прекратить слушать вам необходимо бросить исключение `StopException` или вернуть `False` из обработчика. Функции `on_press`, `on_release` автоматически исполняются не в основном потоке.

Как бонус дополнительно можно слушать события мыши.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать стандартный модуль [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/msvcrt.html).

```
import msvcrt, sys
while True:
    pressedKey = msvcrt.getch()
    if pressedKey == 'q':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "Key:" + str(pressedKey)
```

Плюсы: Присутствует из коробки. Биндинг непосредственно к msvcrt.

Минусы: Кнопки Alt, Ctrl, Shift и все *Lock не ловятся. Работает не во всех окружениях. У меня не работало в PyCharm и GitBash (долго не понимал что происходит, пока не догадался запустить в powershell)