# Как отслеживать события мыши в Python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Каким образом отслеживать события мыши в [python](/questions/tagged/python)? Вообще говоря интересует библиотека `pynput` c его `mouse.Listner`, но это не принципиально. Причём, интересует не только ЛКМ, ПКМ и колёсико, но и дополнительные клавиши, присутствующие на мышке.

P.S. `keyboard.Listner` слушает именно клавиатуру. Он не работает с мышью, проверено.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Слушатель клавиши Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654733/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8-python)

Comment: @IgorSergeevich тот вопрос о клавиатуре. Он не работает с мышью.

Comment: Внимательног посмотрите ответ - можно слушать события мыши

Comment: @IgorSergeevich да, я видел. Пробовал, но реакции на клики не последовало никакой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В документациии  есть [пример](http://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html):

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_move(x, y):
    print('Pointer moved to {0}'.format(
        (x, y)))

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format(
        'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
        (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scrolled {0} at {1}'.format(
        'down' if dy < 0 else 'up',
        (x, y)))

# Collect events until released
with mouse.Listener(
    on_move=on_move,
    on_click=on_click,
    on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```