# как определить нажатие на боковые кнопки мыши пайтон?

Tags: python

как определить нажатие на боковые кнопки мыши пайтон?

Comment: ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/687896/209304)

Answer (score 1):

Похожий вопрос был тут и нашли решения с библиотекой Pyhook - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615989/mouse-side-buttons-in-python

Comment: Ответ на "похожий вопрос" дан на англоговорящем SO и нерелевантен для SO на русском.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через keyboard:

```py
import sys
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    line = ', '.join(str(code) for code in keyboard._pressed_events)
    print('\r' + line + ' ' * 40, end='') # Текущая нажатая клавиша
    if line == "4": 
        print("\nКнопка 4")
    elif line == "5":
        print("\nКнопка 4")

keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

4-5 соответственно боковые кнопки мышки