# Настроить выход по ESC из консольного приложения

Tags: python, консоль, клавиатура, keypress

Пишу программку с бесконечным циклом запроса от пользователя информации. Хочу сделать принудительную клавишу для выхода <kbd>ESC</kbd>. Не получается.

Вот код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import msvcrt

headline= """ 
###############################################################################
#                             Program (программа)                             #
#             conversion of numbers into different number systems             #
#                 конвертация чисел в разные системы счисления                #
###############################################################################

Для выбора напралвение перевода числа из одной ситсемы в другую
Вам требуется указать треьбуемое направление перевода с применением
знака "->". Например, применяемая система по умолчанию выглядит
следующим образом: "10->2".
"""

def convert_base(num, from_base=10, to_base=2):
    # first convert to decimal number
    if isinstance(num, str):
        n = int(num,from_base)
    else:
        n = int(num)
    # now convert decimal to 'to_base' base
    alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    if n < to_base:
        return alphabet[n]
    else:
        return convert_base(n // to_base, to_base) + alphabet[n % to_base]

def int_try(s) ->int:
    try:
        s = name.strip()
        s = s.replace(" ", "")
        i=int(float(str(s)))
    except:
        print("Сработала какая-то ошибка")
        i=-1
    return i

print (headline)
conv_from=10
conv_to=16
work=True
print ("Нажмите <Esc> для закрытия окна")
while work==True:
    name = input("Текущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\nВведите число или переопределите конвертацию:  ".format(conv_from, conv_to))
    key = ord(msvcrt.getch())
    if key == 27:  # ESC
        print("Здесь")
        break
    s = name.strip()
    name = s.replace(" ", "")
    if name.find("->")>=0:
        conv_from=int_try(name[0:name.find("->")])
        conv_to=int_try(name[name.find("->")+2:])
        if conv_from>=0 and conv_to>=0:
            continue
        else:
            conv_from = 10
            conv_to = 2
            #continue
    else:
        num = int_try(name)
        if  num>=0:
            result = convert_base (num,conv_from,conv_to)
            print ("В {0}-ой  системе {1} становится {2}".format(conv_to,num,result))
            ##continue
```

**UPDATE 1**

Немного поработал над собственным кодом.
По материалам по этой [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654733/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8-python) сделал "слушалку" кода. Получается именно так, как я хотел... в любой момент можно нажать "ESC" и закончить работу программы.

Но образовался ряд проблем другого толка:
1) Поскольку в дальнейшем я планирую преобразить программу в *.exe, сделав обычное приложение, то и тестирую я его запуская из под обычной консоли windows. Дк вот, "слушалка" не даёт печатать на экране набираемый пользователем текст. Использование стандартной команды print(s) набираемые пользователем символы, но каждый в новой строке, а если написать print(s,end=''), то перестаёт работать. 
Вопрос. Как сделать нормальный вывод набираемых пользователем символов?

2) На могу и не знаю как выводить сочетания клавиш. Как теперь вводить заглавные буквы и символ >, т.к. он с Shift.

вот код.

Спасибо за науку.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# pip install keyboard
#import keyboard
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import sys

headline= """ 
###############################################################################
#                             Program (программа)                             #
#             conversion of numbers into different number systems             #
#                 конвертация чисел в разные системы счисления                #
###############################################################################

Для выбора напралвение перевода числа из одной ситсемы в другую
Вам требуется указать треьбуемое направление перевода с применением
знака "->". Например, применяемая система по умолчанию выглядит
следующим образом: "10->2".
"""

def convert_base(num, from_base=10, to_base=2):
    # first convert to decimal number
    if isinstance(num, str):
        n = int(num,from_base)
    else:
        n = int(num)
    # now convert decimal to 'to_base' base
    alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    if n < to_base:
        return alphabet[n]
    else:
        return convert_base(n // to_base, to_base) + alphabet[n % to_base]

def int_try(s) ->int:
    try:
        s = name.strip()
        s = s.replace(" ", "")
        i=int(float(str(s)))
    except:
        print("Сработала какая-то ошибка\n")
        i=-1
    return i

#def print_pressed_keys(e):
    #print(e, e.event_type, e.name)

def on_press(key):
    global myinputstring
    global alphabet
    #print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
    s = (str(key)).replace("'", "")
    if alphabet.find(s) >= 0:
        #myinputstring +=s
        sys.stdout.write(s)
        #print(s, "\r")
    pass

def on_release(key):
    global myinputstring
    global name
    global work
    global alphabet
    #print('{0} release'.format(key))
    s=(str(key)).replace("'","")

    if alphabet.find(s)>=0:
        myinputstring+=s
        #print(s, end='')
        #print('\n{0} была нажата'.format(myinputstring))

    if key == Key.enter:
        name=myinputstring
        myinputstring =""
        return False

    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        work=False
        return False

print (headline)
conv_from=10
conv_to=16
work=True
myinputstring=""
alphabet = "->0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

#print ("Нажмите <Esc> для закрытия окна")


while work==True:
    name=""
    print("Текущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\nНажмите <Esc> для закрытия окна\nВведите число или переопределите конвертацию: "
          .format(conv_from, conv_to),end=' ')
    #name = input("Текущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\nВведите число или переопределите конвертацию:".format(conv_from, conv_to))
    # Collect events until released
    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
    print("Работаем со строкой:", name)

    s = name.strip()
    name = s.replace(" ", "")
    if name.find("->")>=0:
        conv_from=int_try(name[0:name.find("->")])
        conv_to=int_try(name[name.find("->")+2:])
        if conv_from>=0 and conv_to>=0:
            continue
        else:
            conv_from = 10
            conv_to = 2
            #continue
    else:
        num = int_try(name)
        if  num>=0:
            result = convert_base (num,conv_from,conv_to)
            print ("В {0}-ой  системе {1} становится {2}\n".format(conv_to,num,result))
            ##continue
```

**UPDATE 2**

Я также обновил свой вариант. Теперь в нём нет глобальных переменных. Проблемы же остались)

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# pip install keyboard
#import keyboard
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from functools import partial
import sys

class Main:

    headline = """ 
    ###############################################################################
    #                             Program (программа)                             #
    #             conversion of numbers into different number systems             #
    #                 конвертация чисел в разные системы счисления                #
    ###############################################################################

    Для выбора напралвение перевода числа из одной ситсемы в другую
    Вам требуется указать треьбуемое направление перевода с применением
    знака "->". Например, применяемая система по умолчанию выглядит
    следующим образом: "10->2".
    """
    name = ""
    conv_from=10
    conv_to=16
    work=True
    myinputstring=""
    alphabet = "->0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    def convert_base(self, num, from_base=10, to_base=2):
        # first convert to decimal number
        #print("num=",num,"from_base=",  from_base, "to_base=", to_base)
        if isinstance(num, str):
            n = int(num,from_base)
        else:
            n = int(num)
        # now convert decimal to 'to_base' base
        if n < to_base:
            return self.alphabet[n+2]
        else:
            return self.convert_base((n+2) // to_base, from_base, to_base) + self.alphabet[(n+2) % to_base]

    def int_try(self, s) ->int:
        in_s=s
        #print("Пришло ", in_s)
        try:
            s = self.name.strip()
            s = s.replace(" ", "")
            i=int(float(str(s)))
        except:
            print("Сработала какая-то ошибка\n")
            i=-1
        #print ("На выходе", i)
        return i

    #def print_pressed_keys(e):
        #print(e, e.event_type, e.name)

    def on_press(self, name, key):
        #print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
        self.name=name
        #print(key)
        #print(name)
        s = (str(key)).replace("'", "")
        if self.alphabet.find(s) >= 0:
            #myinputstring +=s
            sys.stdout.write(s)
            #print(s, "\r")

        if self.alphabet.find(s) >= 0:
            self.myinputstring += s
            #print(s, end='')
            #print('\n{0} была нажата'.format(self.myinputstring))

        if key == Key.enter:
            self.name = self.myinputstring
            self.myinputstring = ""
            return False

        if key == Key.esc:
            # Stop listener
            return False


    def on_release(self, name, key):
        pass



    #print ("Нажмите <Esc> для закрытия окна")

    def __init__(self):
        print (self.headline)

        while True:
            print("Текущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\n"
                  "Нажмите <Esc> для закрытия окна\n"
                  "Введите число или переопределите конвертацию: "
                  .format(self.conv_from, self.conv_to),end=' ')
            #name = input("Текущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\nВведите число или переопределите конвертацию:".format(conv_from, conv_to))
            # Collect events until released
            with Listener(
                    on_press=partial(self.on_press, self.name),
                    on_release=partial(self.on_release, self.name)) as listener:
                listener.join()

            #print("Работаем со строкой:", self.name)

            s = self.name.strip()
            self.name = s.replace(" ", "")
            if self.name.find("->")>=0:
                self.conv_from=int_try(self.name[0:self.name.find("->")])
                self.conv_to=int_try(self.name[self.name.find("->")+2:])
                if self.conv_from>=0 and self.conv_to>=0:
                    continue
                else:
                    self.conv_from = 10
                    self.conv_to = 2
                    #continue
            else:
                num = self.int_try(self.name)
                if  num>=0:
                    result = self.convert_base (num,self.conv_from,self.conv_to)
                    print ("В {0}-ой  системе {1} становится {2}\n".format(self.conv_to,num,result))
                    ##continue


if __name__ == '__main__':

    MyMain=Main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import msvcrt

headline= """ 
###############################################################################
#                             Program (программа)                             #
#             conversion of numbers into different number systems             #
#                 конвертация чисел в разные системы счисления                #
###############################################################################

Для выбора напралвение перевода числа из одной ситсемы в другую
Вам требуется указать треьбуемое направление перевода с применением
знака "->". Например, применяемая система по умолчанию выглядит
следующим образом: "10->2".
"""

def convert_base(num, from_base=10, to_base=2):
    # first convert to decimal number
    if isinstance(num, str):
        n = int(num, from_base)
    else:
        n = int(num)
    # now convert decimal to 'to_base' base
    alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    if n < to_base:
        return alphabet[n]
    else:
        return convert_base(n // to_base, to_base) + alphabet[n % to_base]

def int_try(s) ->int:
    try:
#        s = name.strip()                                          # --- name
        s = s.strip()                                              # +++ s
        s = s.replace(" ", "")
        i=int(float(str(s)))
    except:
        print("Сработала какая-то ошибка")
        i =- 1
    return i

print (headline)
# Текущий конвертер:
conv_from = 10
conv_to   = 16

while True:   # work==True:
#    name = input("Текущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\nВведите число или переопределите конвертацию:  ".format(conv_from, conv_to))

    print ("\nНажмите <Esc> для закрытия окна или любую клавишу для продолжения")
    key = ord(msvcrt.getch())
    if key == 27:               # ESC
        print("Здесь")
        break

    name = input("\nТекущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\nВведите число или переопределите конвертацию:  "
                 "".format(conv_from, conv_to))

    s    = name.strip()
    name = s.replace(" ", "")

    if name.find("->") >= 0:
        conv_from = int_try(name[0:name.find("->")])
        conv_to   = int_try(name[name.find("->")+2:])
        if conv_from >= 0 and conv_to >= 0:
            name = input("Текущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\nВведите число:  "
                 "".format(conv_from, conv_to))

    num = int_try(name)
    if  num >= 0:
        result = convert_base (num, conv_from, conv_to)
        print ("В {0}-ой  системе {1} становится {2}".format(conv_to,num,result))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import msvcrt
from pyautogui import typewrite                        # pip install pyautogui

headline= """ 
###############################################################################
#                             Program (программа)                             #
#             conversion of numbers into different number systems             #
#                 конвертация чисел в разные системы счисления                #
###############################################################################

Для выбора напралвение перевода числа из одной ситсемы в другую
Вам требуется указать треьбуемое направление перевода с применением
знака "->". Например, применяемая система по умолчанию выглядит
следующим образом: "10->2".
"""

def convert_base(num, from_base=10, to_base=2):
    # first convert to decimal number
    if isinstance(num, str):
        n = int(num, from_base)
    else:
        n = int(num)
    # now convert decimal to 'to_base' base
    alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    if n < to_base:
        return alphabet[n]
    else:
        return convert_base(n // to_base, to_base) + alphabet[n % to_base]

def int_try(s) ->int:
    try:
        s = s.strip()                                              
        s = s.replace(" ", "")
        i=int(float(str(s)))
    except:
        print("Сработала какая-то ошибка")
        i =- 1
    return i

print (headline)
# Текущий конвертер:
conv_from = 10
conv_to   = 16
key = None

print ("\nНажмите <Esc> для закрытия окна или делайте перевод чисел.")

while key != 27:   
    print("\nТекущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\nВведите число или переопределите конвертацию (<Esc>-выход): "
          "".format(conv_from, conv_to))
    key = ord(msvcrt.getch())
    if key == 27:               # ESC
        print("\nЗдесь {}".format(key))
        break

    typewrite(chr(key))        
    name = input()
    name = name.strip().replace(" ", "")

    if name.find("->") >= 0:
        conv_from = int_try(name[0:name.find("->")])
        conv_to   = int_try(name[name.find("->")+2:])
        if conv_from >= 0 and conv_to >= 0:
            name = input("Текущий конвертер: {0}->{1}.\nВведите число:  "
                         "".format(conv_from, conv_to))

    num = int_try(name)
    if  num >= 0:
        result = convert_base (num, conv_from, conv_to)
        print ("В {0}-ой  системе {1} становится {2}".format(conv_to,num,result))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так... компромисик ))

Comment: Это Windows-only!

Comment: Не то, что я хотел, может найдётся желающий посмотреть мой второй вариант и скорректировать его?!

Comment: Уважаемый @КириллГуреев ваш комментарий `Ну так... компромисик ))` не совсем мне понятен.
Если мой пример не принес для вас желаемого результата, то напишите, 
что именно вас не устраивает и подумайте над тем, что может вы не совсем четко описали
постановку задачу.
Вам видимо не понравилось избыточное сообщение
`Нажмите <Esc> ...` ?, 
если так, то посмотрите добавленное обновление.
Ваш `второй вариант` посмотреть не могу, т.к. я не приветствую использования
ключевого слово `global`. Для меня глобальные переменные - это зло.

Comment: @S. Nick, простите, если был неконкретным и чрезмерно шутлив)
Ситуация с Вашим кодом такова, что он у меня вообще не выполняется, не идёт дальше ввода пользователем текста. Ну т.е. я текст ввожу, а преобразования не происходит. Но я понял идею, что Вы предлагаете задавать пользователю дополнительный вопрос, а потом выходить на основной алгоритм. Моя же идея заключалась в том, чтобы пользователь мог в любой момент выполнения кода выйти по нажатию клавиши и не реализовывать дополнительных "промежуточных вопросов".
Относительно 'global' сейчас подумаю как исправить.

Comment: @S.Nick, я также обновил свой вариант. Теперь там нет "зла" )